# Backwards ticks (quotes) around dataframe variable names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function which utilizes an API to bring in an array of data objects into R, and converts each data object into both a csv and data frame.

```
API_to_dataframe <- function(dataset) {
  
  #Define data input
  data_input <- paste(dataset,"_data",sep='')
  data_input <- postForm(
    uri=api_url,
    token=api_token,
    content='record',
    format='csv',
    forms=dataset,
    returnFormat = 'csv',
   
  )
  
  #Define data ouput
  connection <- textConnection(data_input)
  data_csv <- read.csv(connection)
  write.csv(data_csv, paste('//Data/',dataset,'.csv',sep=''))
 
  # Convert data to a data frame and assign each data frame a differnt variable name
  d <- data.frame(data_csv)
  assign(paste("df_",dataset),d,envir = .GlobalEnv)
       
}

#Call function by passing in form names as an array and then looping through
API_to_dataframe_parameters <- c("dataset_1",
                                 "dataset_2",
                                 "dataset_3"
                                 )

for (val in API_to_dataframe_parameters) {
  print(paste(val,"completed"))
  API_to_dataframe(val)
}
```

While this works as expected, the one funny thing is that R is putting quotes around the dataframe variables I've created.  When I type the variable in R studio, it autocompletes it with quotes.  For example:

```
`df_dataset_1`
```

It still views as a data frame, but when passing this data frame into other methods and functions, I think this is screwing things up. How can I return these data frame variable names without the funny quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

change:

```
assign(paste("df_",dataset),d,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

to:

```
assign(paste0("df_",dataset),d,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

or (equally):

```
assign(paste("df_",dataset, sep=""),d,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Spaces that are entered in the variable names in `data.frame` cause the quotes. Omitting spaces (e.g. `paste0` or `paste(x,y,sep="")`) in the variable names will solve this.